# What kind of meta argument is the first argument of predicate_property/2?

Tags: module, prolog, iso-prolog, meta-predicate

In other words, should it be `0` or `:` or something else? The Prolog systems SICStus, YAP, and SWI all indicate this as `:`. Is this appropriate? Shouldn't it be rather a `0` which means a term that can be called by `call/1`?

To check your system type:

```
| ?- predicate_property(predicate_property(_,_),P).
P = (meta_predicate predicate_property(:,?)) ? ;
P = built_in ? ;
P = jitted ? ;
no
```

I should add that meta-arguments — at least as in the form used here — cannot guarantee the same algebraic properties we expect from pure relations:

```
?- S=user:false, predicate_property(S,built_in).
S = user:false.

?- predicate_property(S,built_in), S=user:false.
false.
```

Here is the relevant part from ISO/IEC 13211-2:

> #### 7.2.2 predicate_property/2
>
> #### 7.2.2.1 Description
>
> `predicate_property(Prototype, Property)` is true in the
>  calling context of a module `M` iff the procedure
>   associated with the
>  argument `Prototype` has predicate property
>   `Property`.
>
> ...
>
> #### 7.2.2.2 Template and modes
>
> `predicate_property(+prototype, ?predicate_property)`
>
> #### 7.2.2.3 Errors
>
> a) `Prototype` is a variable
>  — `instantiation_error`.
>
> ...
>
> c) `Prototype` is neither a variable nor a callable term
>  —
>   `type_error(callable, Prototype)`.
>
> ...
>
> #### 7.2.2.4 Examples
>
> ```
> Goals attempted in the context of the module
> bar.
>
> predicate_property(q(X), exported).
>     succeeds, X is not instantiated.
> ```
>
> ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats an interesting question. First I think there are two
kinds of `predicate_property/2` predicates. The first kind
takes a callable and is intended to work smoothly with
for example vanilla interpreters and built-ins such as
`write/1`, `nl/0`, etc.., i.e.:

```
solve((A,B)) :- !, solve(A), solve(B).
solve(A) :- predicate_property(A, built_in), !, A.
solve(A) :- clause(A,B), solve(B).
```

For the first kind, I guess the 0 meta argument specifier
would work fine. The second kind of `predicate_property/`2 
predicates works with predicate indicators. Callable
and predicate indicators are both notions already defined
in the ISO core standard.

A predicate indicator has the form F/N, where F is an atom
and N is an integer. Matters get a little bit more complicated
if modules are present, especially because of the operator
precedence of (:)/2 versus (/)/2. If predicate property works 
with predicate indicators, we can still code the vanilla 
interpreter:

```
solve((A,B)) :- !, solve(A), solve(B).
solve(A) :- functor(A,F,N), predicate_property(F/N, built_in), !, A.
solve(A) :- clause(A,B), solve(B).
```

Here we loose the connection of a possible meta argument
0, for example of `solve/1`, with predicate property. Because
`functor/3` has usually no meta predicate declaration. Also
to transfer module information via `functor/3` to 
`predicate_property/2` is impossible, since `functor/3` is agnostic to 
modules, it usually has no realization that can deal with
arguments that contain module qualification.

There are now two issues:
1) Can we give typing and/or should we give typing to predicates
  such as `functor/3`.
2) Can we extend `functor/3` so that it can convey module
  qualification.

Here are my thoughts:
1) Would need a more elaborate type system. One that would 
   allow overloading of predicates with multiple types. For
   example `functor/3` could have two types:

```
  :- meta_predicate functor(?,?,?).
  :- meta_predicate functor(0,?,?).
```

The real power of overloading multiple types would only
   shine in predicates such as (=)/2. Here we would have:

```
  :- meta_predicate =(?,?).
  :- meta_predicate =(0,0).
```

Thus allowing for more type inference, if one side of
   (=)/2 is a goal we could deduced that the other side
   is also a goal.

But matter are not so simple, it would possibly make 
   sense to have also a form of type cast, or some other 
   mechanism to restrict the overloading. Something which
   is not covered by introducing just a meta predicate
   directive. This would require further constructs inside
   the terms and goals.

Learning form lambda Prolog or some dependent type
   system, could be advantageous. For example (=)/2 can
   be viewed as parametrized by a type A, i.e.:

```
 :- meta_predicate =(A,A).
```

2) For Jekejeke Prolog I have provided an alternative 
   functor/3 realization. The predicate is `sys_modfunc_site/2`.
   And it works bidirectionally like `functor/3`, but returns
   and accepts the predicate indicator as one whole thing.
   Here are some example runs:

```
 ?- sys_modfunc_site(a:b(x,y), X).
 X = a:b/2
 ?- sys_modfunc_site(X, a:b/2).
 X = a:b(_A,_B)
```

The result of the predicate could be called a generalized
   predicate indicator. It is what SWI-Prolog already understands
   for example in `listing/1`. So it could have the same meta argument
   specification as `listing/1` has. Which is current : in SWI-Prolog.
   So we would have, and subsequently `predicate_property/2` would
   take the : in its first argument:

```
 :- meta_predicate sys_modfunc_site(?,?).
 :- meta_predicate sys_modfunc_site(0,:).
```

The vanilla interpreter, that can also deal with modules, then
   reads as follows. Unfortunately a further predicate is needed,
   `sys_indicator_colon/2`, which compresses a qualified predicate
   indicator into an ordinary predicate indicator, since our
   `predicate_property/2` does not understand generalized predicate
   indicators for efficiency reasons:

```
solve((A,B)) :- !, solve(A), solve(B).
solve(A) :- 
      sys_modfunc_site(A,I), 
      sys_indicator_colon(J,I), 
      predicate_property(J, built_in), !, A.
solve(A) :- clause(A,B), solve(B).
```

The above implements a local semantic of the colon (:)/2,
   compared to the rather far reaching semantic of the colon
   (:)/2 as described in the ISO module standard. The far 
   reaching semantic imputes a module name on all the literals
   of a query. The local semantic only expects a qualified 
   literal and just applies the module name to that literal.

Jekejeke only implements local semantic with the further
   provision that call-site is not changed. So under the hood 
   `sys_modfunc_site/2` and `sys_indicator_colon/2` have also to 
   transfer the call-site so that `predicate_property/2` makes 
   the right decision for unqualified predicates, i.e. resolving 
   the predicate name by respecting imports etc..

Finally a little epilog:
   The call-site transfer of Jekejeke Prolog is a pure runtime 
   thing, and doesn't need some compile time manipulation, especially
   no ad hoc adding of module qualifiers at compile time. As a result 
   certain algebraic properties are preserved. For example assume 
   we have the following clause:

```
 ?- [user].
 foo:bar.
 ^D
```

Then the following things work fine, since not only `sys_modfunc_site/2`
   is bidirectional, but also `sys_indicator_colon/2`:

```
  ?- S = foo:bar/0, sys_indicator_colon(R,S), predicate_property(R,static).
  S = foo:bar/0,
  R = 'foo%bar'/0
  ?- predicate_property(R,static), sys_indicator_colon(R,S), S = foo:bar/0.
  R = 'foo%bar'/0,
  S = foo:bar/0
```

And of course `predicate_property/2` works with different input and
   output modes. But I guess the SWI-Prolog phaenomenom has first an 
   issue that a bare bone variable is prefixed with the current module. And
   since `false` is not in `user`, but in `system`, it will not show `false`.
   In output mode it will not show predicates which are equal by resolution.
   Check out in SWI-Prolog:

```
 ?- predicate_property(X, built_in), write(X), nl, fail; true.
 portray(_G2778)
 ignore(_G2778)
 ...
 ?- predicate_property(user:X, built_in), write(X), nl, fail; true.
 prolog_load_file(_G71,_G72)
 portray(_G71)
 ...
 ?- predicate_property(system:X, built_in), write(X), nl, fail; true.
 ...
 false
 ...
```

But even if the SWI-Prolog `predicate_property/`2 predicate would 
   allow bar bone variables, i.e. output goals, we would see less 
   commutativity in the far reaching semantic than in the local 
   semantic. In the far reaching semantic `M:G` means interpreting `G` 
   inside the module `M`, i.e. respecting the imports of the module `M`, 
   which might transpose the functor considerable.

The far reaching semantic is the cause that `user:false` means 
   `system:false`. On the other hand, in the local semantics, where `M:G` 
   means `M:G` and nothing else, we have the algebraic property more often.
   In the local semantics `user:false` would never mean `system:false`.

Bye

Comment: My view on this is that `(:)/2` should never by used by a user explicitly. That is, in case this is done, very few can be guaranteed at all. So effectively the colon is something internal.

Comment: I'd say any explicit mentioning/manipulation is implementation dependent. So it is not directly forbidden, but you cannot expect a clear result. In this manner an analysis can detect problematic cases ; and at the same the the implementation in e.g. SICStus can remain the same as it is now.

Comment: It is pretty unrealistic to change SICStus current approach. Defining a "reasonable subset" & methodology is definitely a more promising approach.

Comment: What exact steps do you take to measure this? I cannot see a difference in the JITter